# How do I handle this type issue in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, rethinkdb, dart-null-safety, sqflite

I'm following a tutorial series that creates a messaging app in flutter. It's slightly outdated but I'm trying to follow along with the most updated version.

I'm getting the following error:

```
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
```

For this code snippet: (everything after tryParse is underlined in red).

```
      return chatsWithLatestMessage.map<Chat>((row) {
        final int? unread = int.tryParse(chatsWithUnreadMessages.firstWhere(
          (ele) => row['chat_id'] == ele['chat_id'],
        orElse: () => {'unread': 0})['unread']);
```

I tried adding `.toString()` at the end, but then I get more errors because it's supposed to be int:

```
Use a non-nullable type for a final variable initialized with a non-nullable value.dartunnecessary_nullable_for_final_variable_declarations
A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int?'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'int?'.dartinvalid_assignment
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
```

I also tried adding `.toString()` in a few other places in the code, but then got errors saying that what came after `.toString()` could not be used with Strings.

I think there's something more going on here with all the types. Any ideas what I can do? I'm a total beginner so odds are, the fix is something very basic that I'm just not seeing. I can edit to include more code & files upon request.

This is the whole function that the code snippet lives in:

```
  @override
  Future<List<Chat>> findAllChats() {
    return _db.transaction((txn) async {
      final chatsWithLatestMessage = await txn.rawQuery(''' SELECT messages.* FROM 
      (SELECT
        chat_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
        FROM messages
        GROUP BY chat_id
      ) AS latest_messages
      INNER JOIN messages
      ON messages.chat_id = latest_messages.chat_id
      AND messages.created_at = latest_messages.created_at
      ''');

      final chatsWithUnreadMessages = 
          await txn.rawQuery('''SELECT chat_id, count(*) as unread
      FROM messages
      WHERE receipt = ? 
      GROUP BY chat_id
      ''', ['delivered']);

      return chatsWithLatestMessage.map<Chat>((row) {
        final int? unread = int.tryParse(chatsWithUnreadMessages.firstWhere(
          (ele) => row['chat_id'] == ele['chat_id'],
        orElse: () => {'unread': 0})['unread']).toString();

        final chat = Chat.fromMap(row);
        chat.unread = unread!;
        chat.mostRecent = LocalMessage.fromMap(row);
        return chat;
      }).toList();
    });
  }
```

Edit: here is the chat model:

```
import 'package:rethink_chat/models/local_message.dart';

class Chat {
  late String id; // added late
  int unread = 0;
  List<LocalMessage>? messages = [];
  LocalMessage? mostRecent; // added late

  Chat(this.id, {this.messages, this.mostRecent});

  toMap() => {'id': id};
  factory Chat.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Chat(json['id']);
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of the Chat object? Furthermore, inside your firstWhere method, the orElse clause returns an object { unread : 0 }

Comment: Thanks @tomerpacific , I just updated the post to have the chat object at the bottom. I am following the tutorial exactly, and that's what they do with the orElse, and they did not get an error. I wonder what I have wrong?

Comment: Ok I updated it this way: ```       return chatsWithLatestMessage.map<Chat>((row) {
        final int? unread = int.tryParse(chatsWithUnreadMessages.firstWhere(
          (ele) => row['chat_id'] == ele['chat_id'],
        orElse: () => {'unread': 0})['unread'].toString());``` and now I don't get any red squiggly lines. I think previously I had my .toString outside the last parenthesis instead of inside, and now I hope it works out okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first bug, is that you are declaring the value `final int? unread...` and assign it to value that will never be a `null`, and it will never be null because you are using the `orElse` part,
To solve this, you can do one of the following:
1- declare your `unread` value as a `final int unread`
2- or remove the `orElse` part and set your chat.unread to `chat.unread = unread ?? 0;`

The second bug, is that you've declared the `unread` value as an `int?` but you are assigning it to a string value by writing `orElse: () => {'unread': 0})['unread']).toString()` the `.toString()`
and this must be removed for either of the solutions above

---- Update:

```
  final chatsWithUnreadMessages = 
      await txn.rawQuery('''SELECT chat_id, count(*) as unread
  FROM messages
  WHERE receipt = ? 
  GROUP BY chat_id
  ''', ['delivered']);
```

The above code will return for you a List<Map<String, dynamic>>,
Ex:

```
chatsWithUnreadMessages = [
    {
        "chat_id": 1,
        "unread": 3
    },
    {
        "chat_id": 1,
        "unread": 3
    }
]
```

and after mapping them, the `firstWhere` will return for you a whole record of the list, so if it found a record that mets `row['chat_id'] == ele['chat_id']` it will return the whole row
and the whole row will be something like:

```
{
    "chat_id": 1,
    "unread": 3
}
```

and that is an `Object` to flutter and it is not String so it cannot be parse-able!

```
//Your code
return chatsWithLatestMessage.map<Chat>((row) {
  final int? unread = int.tryParse(chatsWithUnreadMessages.firstWhere(
    (ele) => row['chat_id'] == ele['chat_id'],
  orElse: () => {'unread': 0})['unread']).toString();
    ....

//Updated code
return chatsWithLatestMessage.map<Chat>((row) {
  final int? unread = int.tryParse(chatsWithUnreadMessages
      .firstWhere((ele) => row['chat_id'] == ele['chat_id'],
          orElse: () => {'unread': 0})['unread']
      .toString());
  ...
});
//What I done is I entered the ".toString()" inside the int.tryParse() parenthesis
```

I believe that this would solve the problem

Comment: When I remove the ? from int?, then I get these errors: ```A value of type 'int?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'int'.dartinvalid_assignment
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.```

Comment: Ok, I got it to work by leaving the int?, but then I added .toString() like you said, and now it works. Thank you. Before when I tried to add .toString(), I put it outside the last parenthesis, and now I put it inside and it works.

Comment: Oh, that's good to hear, good luck